# Helium select items from drop down but another element obscures it

Tags: python, selenium, helium

I have a drop down single select combo box.
I can get a reference to that drop down via a CSS selector.

```
<select class="single-option-selector no-select selector single-option-selector-100" data-option="option1" id="product-select-template--15646112383191__main-option-0">
    <option value="15.0cm">15.0cm</option>
    <option value="23.0cm">23.0cm</option>
    <option value="25.0cm">25.0cm</option>
</select>
```

I see in Helium there is a select function which needs two parameter name and value.

How do i pass the name and value to this select function ?

I tried this

```
drop_down = [item.web_element for item in find_all(S(".single-option-selector-0"))][0]
select(drop_down, "23.0cm")
```

But i get a exception

```
    ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element 
    <select  class="single-option-selector no-select selector single-option-selector-0"> 
is not clickable at point (1012,654) 
    because another element 
    <div id="cookie-notification" 
    class="notification-main 
    notification-bottom-center-floating 
bottom-center-floating-small 
bottom-center-floating-default 
    has-default hasCloseIcon animate slide 
    enzuzo-shadow"> 
    obscures it
```

Any ideas how do i circumvent this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_all()` should return you all the desired WebElements and the subscription `[0]` should get ou the desired *`<select>`* element.

Effectively, your code block will be:

```
drop_down = find_all(S(".single-option-selector.no-select.selector.single-option-selector-100"))[0]
select(drop_down, "23.0cm")
```

Comment: I am getting an error AttributeError: 'S' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

Comment: But my error when i use the right css path is ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element obscures it Which i posted in my original question

Comment: The other WebElement which is _intercepting_ your click is the **cookie-notification** popup. Once you access the website, ideally first of all you should accept the _**cookie-notification**_ then proceed with other tasks e.g. selecting options from dropdowns.

Comment: When i visit the website manually and don't accept the cookie the dropdown works so i am curious about your suggestion .Thanks anyway let me figure out this and let me see if it works.

Comment: The _cookie-conscent_ is published for a purpose and without accepting the _T&C_ a lot of WebElements may not render properly. So you don't have a option regaring not accepting the _cookie-conscent_.

Comment: I have another issue lol after accepting cookie it says ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <select 
because another element <iframe id="ba-widget-iframe" src="about:blank"> obscures it Any idea on this one Please?

Comment: Please add clicking cook-consent to the answer not the CSS expression so your answer is helpful to the wider community please :)

Comment: Yeap :) frame/iframe does exists. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.